# Python references

Tags: python, list

I have come across a situation that I believe has revealed a gap in my understanding of how references work in Python.

Suppose that we have two classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3]

    def modify(self):
        self.x.append(4)

    def reset(self):
        self.x = []

class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def say(self):
        print self._x




a = A()
b = B(a.x)

b.say()
a.modify()
b.say()
a.reset()
b.say()
```

The output I expected was:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[]
```

The output I got was:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It seems that when I called `reset()` and set `self.x` to a new list, the reference held by `B` became independent and lived on, thereby becoming a copy instead of a reference.  Is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `reset()` method

```
def reset(self):
    self.x = []
```

does not modify the object stored in `self.x` -- it rather creates a new empty list, which is then stored in `self.x`.  The old list is not altered (and since it is still referenced by `b._x`, it is also not garbage collected).  To get the behaviour you are after, use

```
def reset(self):
    del self.x[:]
```

to empty the existing list instead of creating a new one.

Comment: another way is to use a @property decorator to access x.

Answer (score 3):

When you are assigning a.x to [], you are not cleaning the array rather assign a new empty array to a.x while it's reference: b._x is kept intact. If you want to modify and array in place, in your case delete all of it's contents do this:

```
del a.x[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not _x in B that became a copy but x in A that became another list.